# Using Intent.ACTION_SENDTO produces error 'No apps can perform this action" even though there are two email clients installed

Tags: android

I am attempting to use the email intent in Android Studio 3.01. If I use `ACTION_SENDTO`, I get an error `No apps can perform this action` even though the stock Android email client and the Gmail email app are both installed. If I use `ACTION_SEND` in place of `ACTION_SENDTO`, a screen is shown displaying every app on the device.

My goal is to invoke the default email client directly, without going through an intervening screen. What am I doing wrong?

The code I'm using is:

```
public void sendEmail(View view) {

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();
        Log.i("Email sent!", "");
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityCurrentPlace.this,
                "Email not installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

Thanks to the answer, final working code looks like:

```
public void sendEmail(View view) {

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message...");

    try {
        startActivity(emailIntent);
        finish();
        Log.i("Email sent!", "");
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MapsActivityCurrentPlace.this,
                "Email not installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you have the `finish()` line? Won't this finish the current Activity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, `ACTION_SENDTO` does not take a MIME type. So, get rid of `setType()`. That solves two problems:

1. You are artificially restricting to apps that would claim to support that MIME type
2. `setType()` wipes out your `setData()` call (`setType(type)` is the same as `setDataAndType(null, type)`)

Second, if your goal is to launch an email client directly, get rid of `createChooser()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I use `ACTION_SENDTO` the app crashes. If I remove `createChooser` the app crashes :(

Comment: @hermitjimx: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this. Bear in mind that email clients might not appreciate a `mailto:` `Uri` that does not have an actual email address in it.

Comment: Got it working. Agree with your point about the empty `"mailto:"` - seems like a fudge but can't think of any other way to let the user choose a recipient. For some reason I can't uptick your answer, but very many thanks for your help.